# Json Object Serialization in .Net MVC using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am trying to serialize my Model to Json for a POST request, But everytime a request is made, it gives 400 Bad Request due to non-serialized object.

```
public class AppVersionModel
{
    public Project project { get; set; }

    public String active { get; set; }

    public String createdBy { get; set; }

    public String description { get; set; }

    public String name { get; set; }


    public String obfuscatedId { get; set; }

    public String owner { get; set; }



    /*public String AppName { get; set; }
    public String AppVersion { get; set; }
    public int AppId { get; set; }

    public String Description{ get; set; }

    public String DescriptionForApp { get; set; }

    public String DescriptionForVersion { get; set; }

    public String DevPhase { get; set; }

    public String DevStrategy { get; set; }

    public String IssueTemplate { get; set; }

    public String UserName { get; set; }*/

}


public class Project
{
    /*public String createdBy { get; set; }*/
    [JsonIgnore]
    public String description { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public String issueTemplateId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public String name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller is as follow.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult onboard([FromUri] AppVersionModel appVersionModel)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("<any url>");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            //HTTP POST
            try
            {

                /*string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appVersionModel);*/
                var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<AppVersionModel>("projectVersions",appVersionModel);

                /*var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<AppVersionModel>("appVersionModel", appVersionModel);*/
                postTask.Wait();
                var result = postTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Home/Index");
                }
                else if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Authentication Error. Please contact administrator.");
                    return View(appVersionModel);
                }

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server Error. Please contact administrator.");
            }
            catch (HttpException ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Exception Occured in Http Request.");

            }


            return View(appVersionModel);


        }

    }
```

I get 400 Bad Request Error, My understanding is that as Model object as one complex type i-e "Project", so its not serializing the Model object, hence the request doesn't get required request body.

Anyone can help me in this regard.

Comment: If you use Post then change [FromUri] to [FromBody] and try with postman.

Comment: @FlorimMaxhuni he is not having issues coming into his own controller, he is having issues sending to api once in.

Comment: @Rezwan so you are using another library to tell it to ignore the props of your project. on the client API side, it is trying to intercept your json and decompose it into an object, your ignors are blocking that bc the API recieves something that doesnt map 1:1. API thinks you passed a compeletely different object to its endpoint which it has no mapping. Abstract your model into a new view model for the api to receive which props would be included or you will need to adjust your ignore calls to only json write action

Comment: Changing to  FromBody doesnt help

Comment: I just remove jsonIgnore and added it as jsonProperty but still fails @TravisActon

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
```

You should `PostAsync()` like this:

```
var result = await client.PostAsync("projectVersions", 
                    new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appVersionModel,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

The final code is:

```
    public ActionResult onboard([FromUri] AppVersionModel appVersionModel)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("<any url>");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            try
            {
                var result = await client.PostAsync("projectVersions",
                    new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appVersionModel, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Home/Index");
                }
                else if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Authentication Error. Please contact administrator.");
                    return View(appVersionModel);
                }

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server Error. Please contact administrator.");
            }
            catch (HttpException ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Exception Occured in Http Request.");
            }
        }
        return View(appVersionModel);
    }
```

Comment: Check the modified response

Comment: I cant get past this line.
var result = await client.PostAsync("projectVersions",
                    new System.Net.Http.StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appVersionModel), Encoding.UTF8,"application/json"));*/

Comment: String dummy = "{\"name\":\"john\",\"age\":22,\"class\":\"mca\"}";*/
                HttpContent inputContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dummy), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
I checked StringContent but it still returns empty object.

Comment: I think the problem is with StringContent, can you plz guide me in this regard, I think I am missing something